# Is there any way to get the email address of the one who clicked the link on outlook

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, outlook, office365, mailkit

I developed an application in which all the processes of organization is going to be handle online .
There are some processes which were run manually and it took time , now it is going to approve or disapprove online.

Let say there is an document who is going to be approved by `HR ---> ADMIN ---> CEO.`

Now when some one initiate a request application send two links to HR manager which is approve or disapprove , and HR can perform their action by clicking those link.

What is happening it if HR manager send this links to someone else , SO , That person can also approve or disapprove the process , although he is not the right person to do.

I can stop it by implementing authentication process on those two links , Than every authority must have to login in the application . which i don't want.

Is there any way that i can pick the email id of the person who click that link , so i can compare the email address on back end ?

[image]

Comment: If it was possible, then it would be a security/privacy issue, wouldn't it?

Comment: So , There is no such thing exists ? + Do you know how oracle process approval processes ? does same happen to them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it you have 3 possible ways of doing this:

---

### 1: Implementing an authentication process

This is the best approach in my opinion as you can be sure that the person who should approve the process is the person actually approving it.

The con with this approach is that the users will have to log in, but you could implement this in such a way that they rarely have to, for example they could stay logged in for one a month or longer.

---

### 2: Using a link with a one time token

This is basically the approach you mentioned with the con that you mentioned, namely that someone can just forward the email and someone else can then approve it.

The only way in your case for this to work is if it's enforced from the top down, as in management could impose a penalty if such an email is sent to someone else. But this is rarely a good strategy and would be difficult to enforce.

---

### 3: Approve and Disapprove with a reply email

I think this approach might be the closest to what you're looking for, but as a disclaimer I've not tested something like this before.

You could setup the links in such a way that clicking on them will open a new mail screen with certain things populated, for example you could populate the subject and the address to send the mail to.

Example link: `<a href="mailto:approvedisapprove@system.com?Subject=Approve%20%5BIDNumberHere%5D&body=UniqueID%3D123456" target="_top">Approve</a>`

Then within the system you're creating you'll have to monitor that mailbox and then parse any email received, using the from address to validate if the correct person has sent the email.

A big note with this approach is that the from address in an email can easily be spoofed, so if you want to take this approach, I'd recommend at least adding some sort of random token in the email as well that will be validated on the back end.

Even with the unique token, there exists another vector of attack, although it would take some work. Let's say the system sends a mail to Alice because she needs to approve or disapprove something, she forwards the mail to Bob. Bob can't click on the link and send the email as is, because the system will see that it came from his email address, but what Bob can do is click on the link to see what the subject should be, and then spoof Alice's email using a spoofing site. The system would then see everything as in order because it will look like the email came from Alice.

Example spoofing site: https://emkei.cz/

Comment: Thanks ! You've explained it very well .

Comment: Hi Ettienne , Can i use biometric authentication for the same?

Comment: That should work with option 1 or 2 to confirm that the correct user is approving or declining, but it won't work with option 3

Comment: instead of writing password i can just allow them to scan and go . ? 

Do you have any tutorial regarding the same ? 

Can i use any scanner for scanning the fingerprints ( laptop or mobile phone scanner)

Comment: It should be possible to use some form of biometric authentication instead of a password, but I unfortunately do not have a tutorial with regards to implementing this